# Redux Toolkit - Rexporting selectors gets caught in a cyclic dependancy

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Complete working code: https://github.com/rahulthewall/redux-error

I have my selectors defined in a file selectors.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../store/store';

const userState = (state: RootState) => state.userReducer;

export const user = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.loginUser.data);
export const userIsLoggingIn = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.loginUser.isFetching);
export const userLoginHasError = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.loginUser.hasError);

export const refreshUser = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.refreshUser.data);
export const userIsRefreshing = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.refreshUser.isFetching);
export const userRefrehHasError = createSelector([userState], (userSlice) => userSlice.refreshUser.hasError);
```

In a file `index.ts` in the same folder, I re-export them as follows

```
export * as userSelectors from './selectors';
```

Then, when I try to use this import in my component, it errors out.

Here's how I use it.

```
import { userSelectors } from "./modules/user";

const user = useAppSelector(userSelectors.user);
```

The error I get is the following

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'userReducer' before initialization
```

However, if I import it directly from the `selectors` file it works.

```
import { user } from "./modules/user/selectors";

const userObject = useAppSelector(user);
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake I am making? I can't see it.